# Read Xml file and save content into memory WP7

Tags: c#, xml, windows-phone-7

I have a xml with data, in this case images stored in the internet..i want to read the xml in windows phone and save it to the memory.. how can i do that? any tutorial?

Comment: where do you read/get the file from? where do you want to save it? internal memory?

Comment: i want to read the file from a server and i want to save in internal memory or memory card..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lets divide your task into two parts

**1. Downloading XML file containing image path**

**2. Reading that XML file and binding image control to that dynamic path**

Lets Proceeds with first case:

**1. Downloading XML file containing image path**

here **Path**=http://server_adrs/XML_FILE

**iso_path**=Path inside Isolated Storage where u want to save XML file.

```
    public void GetXMLFile(string path)
    {
        WebClient wcXML = new WebClient();
        wcXML.OpenReadAsync(new Uri(path));
        wcXML.OpenReadCompleted += new OpenReadCompletedEventHandler(wc);

    }

    void wc(object sender, OpenReadCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        var isolatedfile = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication();
        using (IsolatedStorageFileStream stream = new IsolatedStorageFileStream(iso_path, System.IO.FileMode.Create, isolatedfile))
        {
            byte[] buffer = new byte[e.Result.Length];
            while (e.Result.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length) > 0)
            {
                stream.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
            }
            stream.Flush();
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(0);
        }            
    }
```

**2. Reading XML file and binding image control to the dynamic path**

here i am having an List which is showing an images, so i will a function to bind images to this list as per below.

```
    public IList<Dictionary> GetListPerCategory_Icon(string category, string xmlFileName)
    {
        using (var storage = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
        {
            if (storage.FileExists(xmlFileName))
            {
                using (Stream stream = storage.OpenFile(xmlFileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
                {
                    try
                    {
                        loadedData = XDocument.Load(stream);
                        var data = from query in loadedData.Descendants("category")
                                   where query.Element("name").Value == category
                                   select new Glossy_Test.Dictionary
                                   {
                                        Image=GetImage((string)query.Element("iconpress")),//This is a function which will return Bitmap image

                                   };
                        categoryList = data.ToList();
                    }

                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message.ToString(), (((PhoneApplicationFrame)Application.Current.RootVisual).Content).ToString(), MessageBoxButton.OK);
                        return categoryList = null;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        return categoryList;
    }
```

and here the definition for above function

```
     public BitmapImage GetImage(string imagePath)
    {
        var image = new BitmapImage();
        imagePath = "/Glossy" + imagePath;
        using (var storage = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
        {
            if (storage.FileExists(imagePath))
            {
                using (Stream stream = storage.OpenFile(imagePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
                {                       
                    image.SetSource(stream);                        

                }
            }
        }
        return image;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

you could use WebClient to pull the xml from the server and then save it as an XDocument in your callback.